# how to take backup of activemq data restore

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

We are running activemq as pod. Now once the pod is restarted how to take the backup and restore the old topics, messages to new pod.

Comment: Is this OpenShift, Kubernetes? Something else? In general you'd assign the pod some persistent storage from the container framework's storage pool. On OpenShift you might use a deployment configuration to do that. When a pod restarts, it should see the same storage. If you're using storage within the pod's internal filesystem, it will be ephemeral, and will not survive a restart. The trick is to externalize the storage in the infrastructure. However, the methods for doing that depend on the container framework you're using, and a bunch of other factors as well.